# Как вести статистику по дням в БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Хочу делать подсчет сколько раз пользователь нажал на кнопку за период (по дням).

Подумал реализовать так: создать Таблицу (id, idUser, date), но при такой организации получается будут миллионы записей со временем.

Есть ли способ обойтись меньшей нагрузкой?

Comment: а вам нужны прям записи со временем каждого клика? или таки число кликов в сутки?

Comment: Читайте значение за день (создавайте запись если нету), добавляйте +1, Сохраняйте.

Comment: `id` какую нагрузку у вас несет? тут миллионы записей строки из 8байт вам таблицу тяжелой не сделают.